# can't connect to my sqlite database

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, windows-phone-7

i have a windows phone application and am trying to connect to a database. The database is valid, i have verified. I am using codeplex's sqlite client to try to connect.

First i add my database to my project using ">add>Existing item>" and after that i try to connect using the code :

```
db = new SQLiteConnection(@"Database.db");
db.Open();

Debug.WriteLine("DB opened");
SQLiteCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand("SELECT * FROM Tags");
var lst = cmd.ExecuteQuery<Tags>();

foreach (Tags r in lst)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(r.Tag);
}
Debug.WriteLine(":D");
```

My Tags class looks like this :

```
public class Tags
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

And i get an error in the sqlite project ( in `Sqlite3.Vdbe Prepare()`) saying that there is `no such table:Tags` . The table is there, i've viewed the database and the name of the table is correct.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it look like
db = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=Database.db");

Comment: doesn't work, the app can't find the location of the database

Comment: Just realized you're on WP7. I don't think it's supported there. On WP7 you can use either IsolatedStorage or XML files. If you need sql database - create a backend and call it via a web service. I know it's strange as both iOS and Android include sql support by default :(

Comment: @aloneguid from mango (wp7.5) there is a linq to sql database framework(-ish) but there are methods of implementing sqlite (just not natively, but in a way like a wrapper in isolatedStorage, but thought it might work outside of isolatedStorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found that my database must be in the IsolatedStorage. Here is a sample i found useful http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try supplying the full path instead of just the file name. I believe windows phone does not have a "current directory" so the application probably looks in the root folder.

If you supply a file that does not exist to the SQLite client, it will silently create an empty database for you and "connect" to that.

Comment: what is the entire path of a local file defined in the project's root? i try to give it the entire windows path but i guess the winPho7 VM doesn't allow it(outside the app's sandbox)

Comment: You may be able to use `Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).AbsolutePath)` to get the directory of the executable. Also, test `File.Exists(path_to_database)` prior to opening the connection so you can verify this is indeed the issue.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to get the project's root folder then. I have only worked with Windows CE devices (WinCE used to be quite similar to win mobile), no virtual devices. Perhaps someone else can help you with that? It shouldn't freeze, thats for sure.